# Enter and exit browser fullscreen view with Javascript on pressing a key

Tags: javascript

I have an element I want to show full-screen when the user presses the f-key.

**My HTML**

```
<div id="test">
   hello
</div>
```

**My JS**

```
// go fullscreen when pressing 'f' (key 70)
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(key===70){
        requestFullScreen(
            document.getElementById("test")
        );
    }
};

function requestFullScreen(elt) {
    console.log("Requesting fullscreen for", elt);
    if (elt.requestFullscreen) {
        elt.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elt.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elt.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elt.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elt.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elt.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elt.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.error("Fullscreen not available");
    }
}
```

or a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/q5tx42cd/3/).

Opening the element full-screen is working. **My question:** how to close full-screen when the user presses 'f' whenever full-screen is opened? I imagine I need to test whether or not the current view is full-screen or not, and depending on the outcome make the key press event behave differently. How though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether or not the document is in fullscreen mode by using the boolean value `document.fullscreen`. To exit fullscreen you use `document.exitFullscreen()`.

Fiddle that works in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/weft_digital/wrd4yo5s/1/

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if(key===70){
       if(!document.fullscreenElement){
            requestFullScreen(document.getElementById("test"));
        }else{
            document.exitFullscreen()
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Tried it same way, did not help. I mean with full screen is working not exiting screen with letter f

Comment: It seems to be working, thank you. I have to add that it seems to be better to use `document.fullscreenElement` and not `document.fullscreen` because it is deprecated (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreen)

Comment: Oh, nice catch! I updated the answer and fiddle accordingly